# Send button is not working

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I have this template:

```
                    <form role="form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {%  bootstrap_field form.username %}
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            {%  bootstrap_field form.password %}
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-info btn-block">
                      </div>
                    </form>
```

The submit button is not working what I doing bad? i've read other answers and still not working, thanks for your help!!!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a regular HTML form, you would need to specify a couple of attributes in `<form>`
You need to provide a target page where the form will be processed:

```
action="http://script_url_here"
```

You should also specify the method by which the data will be sent (either GET or POST):

```
method="POST"
```

One other thing: you had an extra `</div>` at the end of your form. After making those changes, your form would now look like this:

```
<form role="form" action="http://script_url_here" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        {%  bootstrap_field form.username %}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {%  bootstrap_field form.password %}
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-info btn-block">
    <!-- You had an extra </div> here -->
</form>
```

There are other attributes that could and ought to be specified, but they are optional.